# Reduce time for a mail to time out and send message delivery message to sender

Tags: exchange-server, session-timeout, hybrid

We are running a hybrid setup on our mailserver. on-premis exchange and office 365.
When we send a mail to an address that is not listed on our servers, it takes about 30 minutes to  get the error message.

Is there any way to change how long it takes before the mail times out and give the feedback to the sender?

Comment: please include more details so that more people can help you

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how your mail flow is routed. If your using centralized mail flow through your on-prem Exchange server you can try adjusting the values specified here: [Configure message retry, resubmit, and expiration intervals in Exchange Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/mail-flow/queues/configure-message-intervals?view=exchserver-2019). If you are not using centralized mail flow or routing your mail through EXO then I don't think you can adjust these values.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.